How to reuse multiple chunks of R code together with the markdown text between chunks
I have an R markdown file with the following structure. I am aware that there are ways to reuse multiple chunks using ref.label=c('chunk A', 'chunk B'), and ways to reuse a text session. But how to reuse everything under Tab 1 (including titles A,B, texts A,B, code chunks A,B in exactly the same order and format) in Tab 2?
# Tabls {.tabset}
## Tab 1 
### Title A
text A
```{r chunk A}
code A
```

### Title B
text B
```{r chunk B}
code B
```

## Tab 2

